# Errors with Java Applet on web

Tags: java, html, applet, noclassdeffounderror

A java applet that I wrote works exactly as intended when I run it from the code in the applet viewer on my computer. However, when I uploaded it to my website, I get a series of errors. I looked up the errors but can't find any useful information to help figure out the problem. Here are the errors.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Applet2ClassLoader.java:247)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:249)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:179)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:678)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Plugin2Manager.java:3045)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1497)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Applet2ClassLoader.java:252)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:249)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:179)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:160)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 13 more
Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main
```

I understand that this might not be descriptive enough without a sample of my code but can anyone discern anything from these errors? Thanks

Comment: Are you willing to accept answer?

Answer (score 0):

It simply means the class Main referenced in your code is not included in the applet.

Most likely you did not included the class when exporting to jar.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be great if you included your code, but the problem is likely that you're referencing a class called `Main`, yet none exists in the `CLASSPATH` of the service dumping this exception.

You likely need to either create (or rename!) the source to "`Main.java`" and build a `Main.class` and put it in the correct path or alter the path to reference where `Main.class` (or the archive containing `Main.class`) is stored.